# Loop Through JSON Array [Angular 10]

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular10 and I am trying to loop through a JSON object
but can't work it out.

**My JSON object:**

```
[
{
ID: "2",
testata: "Corriere.it - Homepage",
url: "http://xml2.corriereobjects.it/rss/homepage.xml",
categoria: "QUOTIDIANI"
},
{
ID: "3",
testata: "Open",
url: "https://www.open.online/feed/",
categoria: "NEWS"
},
{
ID: "4",
testata: "ANSA.it",
url: "https://www.ansa.it/sito/ansait_rss.xml",
categoria: "NEWS"
}
]
```

**Part of my Angular script:**

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/myjson.json').subscribe(data => {                     
                datax.forEach(element => {              
                console.log(element.url);
            });
```

**The error**

```
error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Object'.
datay.forEach(element => {
```

Comment: Have you tried to log what's inside `data` after you subscribe? I think it might be an object with `response` property.

Comment: Another question is if you're able to get this `.json` file if you enter that URL in browser?

Comment: thanks Michal, for now i solved the error by defining "any" the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly change your code as below as a temporary fix.

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/myjson.json').subscribe((data: any)=> {                     
            data.forEach(element => {              
            console.log(element.url);
        });
});
```

Typescript expects a type for response by default. If not provided, it assumes as object.

On the side note, it is not recommended to type a value as `any`. Kindly use proper typing for the value.

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is whan you declare the response you call it 'data' but when you try to use it you call it 'datax'

Comment: sorry, you're right, but i just badly copied the code here, the array is always "data"

Comment: so the problem remains? if it does try this:

instead of writing `data => {}`
write `(data: any) => {}`

Comment: In fact I did as adhs91 said (and you too oded) and I solved it, thanks